# Lightweight Text Markup language that can be converted to HTML and LaTeX with a Java library?

Tags: java, html, latex, markup

A simple lightweight markup language like e.g. defined by [Ceole 1.0](http://wikicreole.org/wiki/Home)  could be very useful for use in program and application documentation that is used as the basis for automatically created HTML and LaTeX. Is there any Java library out there that would be able to create HTML AND LaTeX from some markup dialect (creole, markdown, textile or similar)?

Are there any tools or libraries that would make it easier to implement such a library oneself? Starting from scratch gets surprisingly complex when done right.

Comment: This question clearly tries to find a solution for a problem: which markup language to use in order to be able to convert the markup into HTML and LaTeX. There was at the time of the question no solution to this problem. The question does not invite any spam or opiniated answers since instead of many possible libraries, there is hardly one that can be used.
Closing this question seems therefore unneccessary, contra-productive and clearly against the intention of the rule that is cited -- and the rule does not apply really since the question is for a language not what is the best of many libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, Fletcher Penney's [Multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) is about a comprehensive as you'll get for a markup language, and there appear to be a number of [Java implementatons](http://www.w3.org/community/markdown/wiki/MarkdownImplementations). HTML creation is standard and more fully-featured than the [original Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (e.g. tables, definition lists), but Fletcher has also thought a lot about [LaTeX](http://fletcher.github.io/peg-multimarkdown/).

There's also a [useful community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/multimarkdown), which might help with further details.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question before it could get marked needlessly and contra-productively as off-topic by some people who obviously think the letter of a rule is more important than its intention.
And who were obviously not even capable of correctly understanding my question which regards solving a problem, not getting an opinion about libraries.