# Markup Language To Pdf or Html

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf, markup

Is there a markup language that can be used in conjunction with a well supported .net open source project to generate PDF or HTML documents with very fine control on the output in terms of style and anchoring for both ?

Documents will part be static and part auto generated from the xml comments of some class libraries.

To Clarify the question, I Know html is a markup language, The reason I don't want to use it to directly store the content is because all of the HTML to PDF tools and libraries I have looked at contain patchy support for creating tables of contents, indexes and turning hyperlinks in to PDF document anchors.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. Do you mean something like XSL:FO?

Comment: The questions is not clear to me.  HTML is a markup language.   You are looking for a markup language for the source document that be be rendered to both PDF and HTML?

Comment: Then look at XSL:FO as commented by Mike B.  Base language of XHTML.  Or a base of HTML as there are HTML to PDF converters.  Would not use PDF as the base - from PDF is a more complex.

Comment: Multimarkdown will generate HTML and PDF. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091195/123033 As for .net integration, that's not so clear, see http://forums.markdownpad.com/discussion/41/multimarkdown-support/p1

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for HTML documents.  [Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) comes to mind.  But as far as 'very fine' control goes arbitrarily, you can always just use HTML.. it is THE HyperText Markup Language after all.

Answer (score 0):

There were many questions like this before on stackoverflow. I think the consensus is that you should have one markup language, rather than two.

HTML is - by definition (hypertext MARKUP LANGUAGE) - the markup language of choice and all you need to do is convert that to PDF. The other way around, from PDF to HTML is quite a bit tougher.

In order to convert HTML to PDF there's a truckload of tools, depending on what exact needs you have for the resulting PDF and what kind of CSS you need to support.

I'd always go for a rendering engine that's used in browsers (instead of something like iText or Prince), because you want to make sure your docs look like they do in a browser. You'd end up with [Winnovative](http://www.winnovative-software.com/Html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx) or something based on WebKit like the [API by htm2pdf](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/html-to-pdf-api).

Comment: None of the HTML Solutions I have looked at contain much support at all for generating contents tables or indexes and that sort of thing.

Comment: The problem with indexes in HTML is that you want pagination. And HTML content is not paged in a continuous way like documents. So you'd have to create your own HTML index, by referring to the other HTML pages - sort of like a sitemap. Come to think of it - there's actually an open source tool, called wkhtmltopdf, which DOES allow you to create outlines and cover pages and stuff like that. That's probably worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

XSL-FO is the recommended solution. It provides a great level of control over the document layout and there are several tools for XSL-FO to PDF comversion.